# Highcharts not updating data on ajax response data

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have created highchart spline chart with ajax call on the button the response data not creating chart but when I put those response data in it works !!!!

it works with static data but not with exact same as ajax response  ,  I have tried to redraw it as well but didn't work, response data is shown as comment in code

```
//    categories: [1574411460000,1574418104000,1574421704000,]
 // series: [{data: [30,30,50,100]},{data: [50,50,80,100]},{data: [200,200,500,600]},]



   $(document).ready(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        $("#gobtn").click(function () {

            var tenant_id = $('#tenantId').val();
            var trunk_id = $('#trunkId').val();
            completedCallGraph(tenant_id, trunk_id);
        });

        function completedCallGraph(tenant_id = '', trunk_id = '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "completedcallgraph?tenant_id=" + tenant_id + "&trunk_id=" + trunk_id,
                success: function (result) {

                    var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);

                    console.log(resultObj.inserted_at);
                    console.log(resultObj.callDetails);

                    var inserted_at = resultObj.inserted_at;
                    var callDetails = resultObj.callDetails;


                  $('#container').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            zoomType: 'xy',
                            panning: true,
                            panKey: 'shift'
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'CallPath Utilization'
                        },

                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Click and drag to zoom in. Hold down shift key to pan.'
                        },
                        xAxis: [{
                            type: 'datetime',
                           categories: inserted_at
                          //    categories: [1574411460000,1574418104000,1574421704000,]

                            ,
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M', this.value);
                                }
                            },
                        }],
                        series: callDetails
                       // series: [{data: [30,30,50,100]},{data: [50,50,80,100]},{data: [200,200,500,600]},]

                  });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Milan Suthar, Any errors in the console? When I removed `JSON.parse` all works. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v1w84Lk3/

Answer (score 1):

As for me would be better to use some separated Highchart drawing function like:

```
function drawHighchar(selector, cates, sers){

Highcharts.chart(selector, {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            zoomType: 'xy',
                            panning: true,
                            panKey: 'shift'
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'CallPath Utilization'
                        },

                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Click and drag to zoom in. Hold down shift key to pan.'
                        },
                        xAxis: [{
                            type: 'datetime',
                           categories: cates,
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M', this.value);
                                }
                            },
                        }],
                        series: sers
                        });
}
```

Here `selector` takes an **id** of DOM element where chart would be placed after, `cates` array of categories and `sers` array of objects with data.

I've used your datasets and other one:

```
let ser1 = [{data: [30,30,50,100]},{data: [50,50,80,100]},{data: [200,200,500,600]},],
    ser2 = [{data: [11,22,33,44]},{data: [33,44,22,11]},{data: [111,333,500,600]},],
    cats1 = [1574411460000,1574418104000,1574421704000,],
    sel = 'container';
```

During first loading it would present `ser1` and after clicking some button the second data `ser2`:

```
drawHighchar(sel, cats, ser1);

$('#cli').click(()=>{ 
 drawHighchar(sel, cats, ser2);  
});
```

Here you should use `resultObj.inserted_at` as `cats` and `resultObj.callDetails` as `ser` arguments.

```js
let ser1 = [{data: [30,30,50,100]},{data: [50,50,80,100]},{data: [200,200,500,600]},],
    ser2 = [{data: [11,22,33,44]},{data: [33,44,22,11]},{data: [111,333,500,600]},],
    cats = [1574411460000,1574418104000,1574421704000,],
    sel = 'container';
 
drawHighchar(sel, cats, ser1);

$('#cli').click(()=>{ 
 drawHighchar(sel, cats, ser2);  
});

function drawHighchar(selector, cates, sers){

Highcharts.chart(selector, {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            zoomType: 'xy',
                            panning: true,
                            panKey: 'shift'
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'CallPath Utilization'
                        },

                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Click and drag to zoom in. Hold down shift key to pan.'
                        },
                        xAxis: [{
                            type: 'datetime',
                           categories: cates,
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M', this.value);
                                }
                            },
                        }],
                        series: sers
                        }); 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<input type="button" id="cli" value="button_click"/>
```

Change your `$.ajax` as following:

```
var sel = "container";
$.ajax({
       url: "completedcallgraph?tenant_id=" + tenant_id + "&trunk_id=" + trunk_id,
       method: "GET",
       success: function (result) {
           var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
           drawHighchar(sel, resultObj.inserted_at, resultObj.callDetails); 
       }
})
```

If you have a problem till this moment then you can try to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Your JS code would be next:

```
  $("#gobtn").click(function () {

       var tenant_id = $('#tenantId').val();
       var trunk_id = $('#trunkId').val();
       var sel = "container";

       var prom1 = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ 

       var ar = [];

        $.ajax({
            url: "completedcallgraph?tenant_id=" + tenant_id + "&trunk_id=" + trunk_id,
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {

              var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);

              ar.push(resultObj.inserted_at);
              ar.push(resultObj.callDetails);

              resolve(ar);
            }
        })   // ajax end
    })       // promise end

   prom1.then((val)=>drawHighchar(sel,val[0],val[1]))

}); // click end
```

```js
var ser1 = [{data: [30,30,50,100]},{data: [50,50,80,100]},{data: [200,200,500,600]},],
    ser2 = [{data: [11,22,33,44]},{data: [33,44,22,11]},{data: [111,333,500,600]},],
    cats = [1574411460000,1574418104000,1574421704000,],
    sel = 'container';
 
drawHighchar(sel, cats, ser1);
  
$("#gobtn").click(function () {
 
     //  var tenant_id = $('#tenantId').val();
     //  var trunk_id = $('#trunkId').val(); 

       var prom1 = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ 
        
       var ar = [];
     /*
        $.ajax({
            url: "completedcallgraph?tenant_id=" + tenant_id + "&trunk_id=" + trunk_id,
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {

              var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
 
              ar.push(resultObj.inserted_at);
              ar.push(resultObj.callDetails);

              resolve(ar);
            }
        }) */  // ajax end
        
              ar.push(cats);
              ar.push(ser2);
              
              resolve(ar);
    })       // promise end

   prom1.then((val)=>drawHighchar(sel,val[0],val[1]))

}); // click end

function drawHighchar(selector, cates, sers){

Highcharts.chart(selector, {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'line',
                            zoomType: 'xy',
                            panning: true,
                            panKey: 'shift'
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'CallPath Utilization'
                        },

                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Click and drag to zoom in. Hold down shift key to pan.'
                        },
                        xAxis: [{
                            type: 'datetime',
                           categories: cates,
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M', this.value);
                                }
                            },
                        }],
                        series: sers
                        }); 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<input type="button" id="gobtn" value="button_click"/>
```

These two ways are working well. I guess you have a problem with `$.ajax` cause of `GET` method, try to use `POST` and make everything for retrieving data via `POST`.

Comment: thanks for time but stil it is not working, I believe it has problem with redraw could you please tell me how to redraw. i modified my code according to yours but same it has problem when variable value comes from ajax call, same response data  works well but with ajax it fails .

Comment: @MilanSuthar, added the second way. I'm suggestion to you to change method of your `$.ajax`.